# Where can I see the code of application that is running using docker images and container

Tags: node.js, docker, amazon-ec2

I have started learning Docker recently. I created an image for my node app and pushed to AWS instance and running the app there in a container. I got a question here, where is my code in that AWS instance? Where can I see my code files? Can anyone please guide?

Comment: What do you mean?  The application is running in a container within docker within your AWS instance.  Use the `docker ps` command to see a list of running containers.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I am asking about the code. Cant I see the code (that I can see in my localmachine) in the server when running in a docker container?

Comment: Not necessarily, please consider posting the Dockerfile you used to create your image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the content of your running container you must enter the following command:

`docker exec -ti <container_name> sh`

This will open a shell from inside your container.
You can navigate inside your container and see all the files you put in your image.